# Rsync with delete option but excluding subfolders

Tags: rsync

I need to sync a local directory (destination) from the remote server directory (source) with the `--delete` option.
I've got this:

Local directory is `/home/user/config` and into it

```
removeit.txt
bar.csv
foo.h
config.conf
scripts <- Is a directory
logs <- Is adirectory
```

The remote directory is `config` and into it

```
bar.csv
foo.h
```

I want in the local directory after rsync

```
bar.csv
foo.h
config.conf
scripts <- Is a directory
logs <- Is adirectory
```

I've tested with multiple options but I can't get a entire rsync command with my needs.

```
rsync -avz --min-size=1 --delete -e "ssh" user@example.com:./config/ ./config --exclude ./config/scripts --exclude ./config/logs --exclude ./config/device.conf --dry-run
```

With a list of include files

```
rsync -avz --min-size=1 --include-from=list --exclude=* --delete-excluded -e "ssh" user@example.com:.config/ config/
```

But nothing works as I expected. The subfolders in the destination are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The [man page for rsync](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.1) has a section on "Include/Exclude Pattern Rules" which you should review. In particular, it looks like you are using `./` to refer to the directory relative of your shell's working directory which won't work the way you want.

Here is a relevant section of the documentation:

> if the pattern starts with a / then it is anchored to a particular
> spot in the hierarchy of files, otherwise it is matched against the
> end of the pathname. This is similar to a leading ^ in regular
> expressions. Thus /foo would match a name of "foo" at either the "root
> of the transfer" (for a global rule) or in the merge-file's directory
> (for a per-directory rule). An unqualified foo would match a name of
> "foo" anywhere in the tree because the algorithm is applied
> recursively from the top down; it behaves as if each path component
> gets a turn at being the end of the filename. Even the unanchored
> "sub/foo" would match at any point in the hierarchy where a "foo" was
> found within a directory named "sub". See the section on ANCHORING
> INCLUDE/EXCLUDE PATTERNS for a full discussion of how to specify a
> pattern that matches at the root of the transfer.

The pattern you are using might be causing rsync to look for a folder literally called `.` which contains a file or folder called `scripts` or whatever.

Try replacing the relative-ish `./config/` part with `/` in your exclude patterns. That will anchor the pattern in the "root of transfer" which is the directory you are synchronizing. In other words, try this:

```
rsync -avz --min-size=1 --delete -e "ssh" user@example.com:./config/ ./config --exclude /scripts --exclude /logs --exclude /device.conf --dry-run
```

I hope that works. If it's not too late to check, please let me know if this worked for you.